# Bibliography style for a particular entry

Tags: bibliographies

I wanted to get the following in my bibliography:

> Moazzeni AR, Nabaei M, Shahbazi K, Shadravan A. Mechanical Earth modelling improves drilling efficiency and reduces non-productive time (NPT). SPE Deep Gas Conference and Exhibition, 24-26 January, 2010, Bahrain. Paper SPE 131718.

I created using `apa` style.

And in my `bib` file, the reference is:

```
@misc{Moazzeni2010,
   author = {Moazzeni, Ali Reza and Nabaei, Mohammad and Shahbazi, Khalil and Shadravan, Arash},
   title = {Mechanical Earth Modelling Improves Drilling Efficiency and Reduces Non-Productive time (NPT)},
   publisher = {Society of Petroleum Engineers},
   month = {2010/1/1/},
   ISBN = {978-1-55563-275-5},
   DOI = {10.2118/131718-MS},
   year = {2010},
   type = {Conference Paper}
}
```

My question is:

- Using the `bib` file, how do can I get the desired output?
- I have the conference name, but I just don't know what should I called it in the `bib`
- The same thing for the paper code: "Paper SPE 131718", I just don't know what should I called it in the `bib`

Can anyone help me please? I am new to Latex

Comment: Please explain how one should go from `month = {2010/1/1/}` and `year={2010}` to `24-26 January, 2010`. And, in the `title` field, why is only the word "Earth" capitalized while the remainder of the field is converted to lowercase?

Comment: You could start by changing the entry type from `@misc`, changing the `type` field from `type = {Conference Paper}` to `type = {Paper SPE}`, and adding the fields `number = 131718` and `address = {Bahrain}`.  Do note that the `apa` bib style does NOT (a) render the abbreviate given names the way you need them, (b) display the contents of the `month` field, and (c) place the `year` field where you say it has to go. It's not clear to me why you're using the `apa` bib style given that its formatting settings are not even close to what you need.

Comment: Incidentally, how is BibTeX supposed to generate the string "SPE Deep Gas Conference and Exhibition" if it's not contained in the bib file?

Comment: Please, you are free to modify the bib file as needed. I have no clue how to achieve what I want. I dont know how to modify the bib, in a way that what should I call the "SPE Deep Gas Conference and Exhibition", etc. The goal is to achieve what is written at the top ;)

Comment: I don't know of any readily-available bibliography style that implements your formatting requirements exactly. I can only suggest that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utillity, which is part of the `custom-bib` package, in order to create a new bst file from scratch. Open a command window and type `latex makebst` to get started. You'll be led through a series of questions, each with multiple-choice answers, with one possible answer marked as the default. The end product is a custom bst file that meets of all of your bibliography-related formatting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the standard types for articles in conference proceedings (@InProceedings), articles in collections (@InCollection)? Sometimes not all the fields are exactly right, but they are close.

Nothing in what you state is really outside a @InProceedings... AUC-TeX for emacs suggests (OPT is optional fields):

```
@InProceedings{,
  author =   {},
  title =    {},
  booktitle =    {},
  OPTcrossref =  {},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTpages =     {},
  OPTyear =      {},
  OPTeditor =    {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTseries =    {},
  OPTaddress =   {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTorganization = {},
  OPTpublisher = {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```